# How was Chell picked?

Tags: video-games, portal

Chell is the tenacious lead character of the Portal Games, but I was wondering why out of all the former employees of Aperture Science was she picked? Was she just the last survivor, or was there a reason she was brought of stasis?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is explained in [Portal 2: Lab Rat comic book](http://half-life.wikia.com/wiki/Portal_2%3a_Lab_Rat). Despite the name, it also explain some of the event prior to the first Portal game. Here a quote from [her article on half-life.wikia](http://half-life.wikia.com/wiki/Chell#Background).

> According to the psychological profile in her personnel file, Chell is "abnormally stubborn" and refuses to ever give up, no matter how daunting the challenge. Originally, she was rejected as a test subject, but [Doug Rattmann](http://half-life.wikia.com/wiki/Chell#Background). altered the testing order, having correctly guessed that Chell's extreme tenacity might allow her to defeat GLaDOS.

You could freely and legally [read it here](http://www.thinkwithportals.com/comic/). You could see the flashback of Chell's selection on [page 21](http://www.thinkwithportals.com/comic/#21) and the alteration the testing order on [page 22](http://www.thinkwithportals.com/comic/#22). The details of her personnel file are in [page 27](http://www.thinkwithportals.com/comic/#27).